# Change style attribute of a generated div on click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

I'm messing around with vue-cli and I'm facing an issue.

I have a row of 24 div who are generated like this:

```
 <template>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="hour" v-on:click="colorize" v-for="n in 24"></div>
   </div>
 </template>
```

I'm trying to change the background color of the clicked `hour` div, based on a saved value in a VueX store, but that's not the important part

Here is my methods :

```
methods: {
  colorize() {
    if(this.$store.state.picked === 1) {
      this.style.backgroundColor="rgb(103, 103, 103)";
    }
  }
}
```

The store works, the issue comes from the 'this' attribute, that I'm using wrong I assume.

Any tips? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` refers to Vue instance not to the clicked element so you should do :

```
 methods: {
   colorize(event) {
     if(this.$store.state.picked === 1) {
       event.target.style.backgroundColor="rgb(103, 103, 103)";
     }
   }
 }
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      elements: [
      {content:'content 1',tooltip:'tool tip 1'},
      {content:'content 2',tooltip:'tool tip 2'},
      {content:'content 3',tooltip:'tool tip 3'},
      {content:'content 4',tooltip:'tool tip 4'},
      ]
    }
  }
, methods: {
   colorize(event) {
 
       event.target.style.backgroundColor="rgb(103, 103, 103)";
     
   }
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app" data-app>

 <div class="row">
     <div class="hour" v-on:click="colorize" v-for="n in elements">
     {{n.content}}
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was that :)